# Allocated memory for returning values in C

Tags: c, garbage-collection, free

If the return value of a function, say, `myFunc`, is an allocated space. Does the parent function still need to free that part of the memory?

For example:

```
char * myFunc() {
    return malloc(5);

    // free() not called
}

int main() {
    char * str = myFunc();

    // does str need to be freed?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the long run, _someone_ has to free the allocated memory, or else you will have a memory leak. In your case, the OS will clean up the memory, but if your program calls `myFunc` in a loop, you may run our of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To free() or not to free()?

When a process terminates, all of its memory is returned to the system, including heap memory allocated by functions in the malloc package. In programs that allocate memory and continue using it until program termination, it is common to omit calls to `free()`, relying on this behavior to automatically free the memory. This can be especially useful in programs that allocate many blocks of memory, since adding multiple calls to `free()` could be expensive in terms of CPU time, as well as perhaps being complicated to code.
Although relying on process termination to automatically free memory is acceptable for many programs, there are a couple of reasons why it can be desirable to explicitly free all allocated memory:

**1.** Explicitly calling `free()` may make the program more readable and maintainable in the face of future modifications.

**2.** If we are using a malloc debugging library to find memory leaks in a program, then any memory that is not explicitly freed will be reported as a memory leak. This can complicate the task of finding real memory leaks.

**3.** To avoid [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 1):

It is *recommended* that `str` is to be freed: replace `// does str need to be freed?` with `free(str)`. This is good programming practice to avoid potential memory leaks.

In your case, the OS will clean up the allocated memory taken by this short program.